# Free RTOS Circular Queue

Tags: c++, queue, freertos

I have a Free RTOS queue that I'd like to use as a circular queue. ie. add elements to, then once full, pop the front of the queue and then push to the back of the queue.

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,3]
[2,3,4] //queue full, so remove front and then push.
```

As far as I know, this can be done using

```
if(uxQueueSpacesAvailable(...)
{
    xQueueSend(...);
}
else
{
    xQueueReceive(...);
    xQueueSend(...);
}
```

But I don't like this solution at all, it's not really descriptive or logical to read the queue here. It also has additional delays.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Additionally, is there any way to access all the elements in the queue, without removing them?

Comment: The sequence has also a race condition if the receiver task receives an item between the queue full-check and the sender queue pop-receive. Better review your design to avoid queue overflow situations.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Flag that whenever there is no more space in the Queue to mark it true, this way you only have to access the flag (bool value) instead of the entire Queue. If once filled, you still expect for your queue to free space, then you can change this, but the logic would start to be a little more of a hassle, and the advantage compared to your current solution would be minimal. so...

```
bool full = false;

if (full) {
    xQueueReceive(...);
    xQueueSend(...);
}
else
{
    xQueueSend(...);
    if (!uxQueueSpacesAvailable(...)) {
       full = true;
    }
}
```

And regarding wether or not it is possible to read a whole Queue without removing elements, the answer is yes and no, there is no true Api call for this, there is xQueuePeek which you can use to see without removing the next, but only that. What you can do, is use xQueuePeek to see the size and position (memory wise obviously) of the first element, so you can then locate the next one, and then repeat, but this time manually seeing the data stored, here is a link with a similar implementation https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/May_2016/freertos_How_to_traverse_a_queue_0be515fcj.html